# Extract number on string and use as filter

Tags: sql, substring, where-clause, teradata

I would like to extract a number in a string and use it as a filter.

My data looks like this:

```
 AAAA_01_01_AAA
 BBBB_01_02_BBB
 CCCC_01_03_CCC
 DDDD_01_04_DDD
```

I would like to extract the 2nd set of numbers [01,02,03,04] and use it as a filter like below

```
where substr(colname,9,2) > 4
```

Its giving me an error

```
 2621: Bad character in format or data of TVM.TVMName
```

I tried converting it to integer as below, but no luck.

```
 where cast(substr(colname,9,2) as int) > 4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS is this? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: What is the problem with the `cast()` version?

Comment: still getting the same error 2621: Bad character in format or data of TVM.TVMName

Answer (score 3):

Since you are inspecting a character variable, I think it would be much safer to stay with character processing.  If your data rows have different formats, you might get errors converting the sub-strings to numbers.

In other words, try this:

```
where substring(colname from 9 for 2) between '05' and '99'
```

Note this starts with '05' because your original question is "greater than 4".

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the `POSITION()` function:

```
SELECT TVMName
  FROM DBC.TVM
 WHERE POSITION('04' IN TVMName) = 9;
```

**Edit**

Misread your question. The following SQL will convert the output of SUBSTRING to a SMALLINT:

```
SELECT 'DDDD_01_04_DDD'
     , CAST(SUBSTRING('DDDD_01_04_DDD' FROM 9 FOR 2) AS SMALLINT) AS Token_
 WHERE Token_ > 4;
```

This query returns no rows because the Token_ is in fact 4.

Have you tried `SUBSTRING()` in favor of the Teradata extension `SUBSTR()`? They are supposed to work identically in 99% of all cases.

Comment: I need to extract the integer value in the text. I don't think position function will give me the right output on that.